# Remove US channel in sylius fixtures

Tags: symfony, sylius

Hello I am trying to setup my development environment for sylius 1.6.4 and added some custom fixtures in config/packages/dev/_sylius_fixtures.yaml :

```
sylius_fixtures:
    suites:
        default:
            fixtures:
                locale:
                    options:
                        locales: ['fr_FR']
                currency:
                    options:
                        currencies: ['EUR']
                channel:
                    options:
                        custom:
                            fr_web_store: # creating new channel
                                name: "FR Web Store"
                                code: "FR_fr"
                                locales:
                                    - "%locale%"
                                currencies:
                                    - "EUR"
                                enabled: true
                                hostname: "localhost"
```

I also set my default local in the framework.yaml to fr.

When I run the fixtures this will create my FR channel correctly. However the US channel will still always be present and even if I try and remove it from within the admin panel I get an error stating that the channel cannot be removed because it is in use.

From reading the Sylius docs I gather that you can have multiple fixture *suites* but I would like to avoid having to create a separate suite when all I really need is to add my FR channel and get rid of the default US channel.

If anyone has any suggestions that would be awesome.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to en_US being the default locale in services.yaml

```
parameters:
    locale: en_US
```

change it here and that will create a new locale if the same locale isn't already added through fixtures. At least that is how I was able to solve it.